# Python: TypeError an integer is required(got type str)

Tags: python

```
print(Datedetail) -> 2020-10-31 00:00:00
print(type(Datedetail) -> <class 'datetime.datetime'>
print (DateDetail.replace('-',''))[:6]) -> TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Datedetail is having value of date and time but while replace special char and having only date details it is giving error as integer is required.

Comment: What are you trying to do with that `replace`? You are using it as if it was [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace), but it is [`datetime.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.replace).

Comment: `replace` works on `string` types, not `datetime` types. You can cast `DateDetail` into a `string` and then do `replace`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the `str.replace()` method on a `datetime.datetime` class.

Use `str` to convert it into a string:

```
print(str(Datedetail).replace('-','')[:6])
```

Output:

```
202010
```

---

Recommendation: use [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime) instead of `datetime`.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of .strftime() to get dates into format you want.

```
Datedetail.strftime('%Y%m')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The replace function is not the same as you use for strings.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.replace

You have to make it to a string first, so it has its usual behaviour:
`print(str(Datedetail).replace('-','')[:6])`

But usually you would use string formatting as you can find as well in the documentation above: `date.strftime(format)`